# Can i write a modern/good game without using actors/sprites

Tags: libgdx

I have got one sily question. I write a game in libgdx. But my friend always use actors and sprites. But i dont use this class. In all parts or elements of game i extends Sprite. Then i use a array list for using to save elements.
I write game like that: reading input, update, check collision and render. Its ok or not ?

Comment: I never use actors and stage2d in my games, and I never extend the Sprite class for my objects... Use whatever you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no fixed way to go from A to B in programming. I have made a couple of good functioning games without the use of the stage and sprite class. These classes just help you get things done quicker. So yes you can write good games without the use of actors/sprites. It is even possible to write good games without the use of OpenGL or DirectX and create your own graphics library, but why should we? If you know what Scene2D and the sprite class can do for you it is kinda ignorant to leave them aside if they can help you.

It often takes little time to learn a certain library/extension. Once we know how to use it there will be profit for life.